# Does the Dell PowerEdge R240 support booting from M.2 NVMe drives?

Tags: dell-poweredge, nvme

Did anybody try whether the Dell PowerEdge R240 (or the 14th generation in general) supports booting from M.2 NVMe disks inserted through some (non-Dell) PCIe-M.2-adapter card? Dells manual doesn't mention it, unfortunately.

I know that older models (such as the R230/R330) had issues with such setups, but the older models also didn't have any official support for NMVe disks in general. Did maybe anybody try this already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not. The R240 doesn't show the inserted PCIe M.2 disks as boot option.

Comment: I have a number of Dell servers and am actually rather intrigued by this - I would have expected it to work, after all, what you are effectively describing is a BOSS card. The only prerequisite is that UEFI would have to have the requisite drivers to pick up the drive. Remember: the drive won't show up as a boot option UNLESS you have a UEFI compatible FAT partition on the drive header. When you tested this are you sure you 1) Had the requisite FAT partition and 2) The device isn't in legacy boot mode?